# Equivalent of \DeclareMathOperator in mathjax?

Tags: mathjax

How do I achieve the same effect in mathjax?

Inserting,

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
```

in the html does not work, mathjax throws `Undefined control sequence \DeclareMathOperator` error. I can, however use `newcommand. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the AMSmath extension (which is included in all the pre-defined configuration files, so I'm assuming you are using your own configuration).  Add

```
TeX: {
  extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js"]
}
```

to your configuration and that should do it.

**EDIT**:
Also, it looks like `orgmode.org` has an **ancient** version of MathJax installed (v1.0.1) that is several *years* out of date. The configuration process that I gave you was added in v2.0, so that is why that isn't being loaded. It may also be that `\DeclareMathOperator` was not in v1.0.1 (I kind of recall that it wasn't). You should switch to http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js to get a current version.

Comment: I am actually using org-mode to export the html and it seems that the default config for org-mode also contains the extensions.

Comment: Can you use your browser's developer tools to see if the AMSmath.js file has been loaded?

Comment: Strangely, I do not think the ext is loaded (chrome's js tool does not show amsmath.js). How do I fix this?
Here is the generated html http://pastebin.com/thAeWmnx

Comment: The configuration is not being done properly.  The configuration has to be present before MathJax is loaded, whereas your file has the configuration following the loading of MathJax.js.  Instead, the configuration script must come before the one that loads MathJax.js and should have `type="text/x-mathjax-config"` rather than `type="text/javascript"`.  If you can't do that, there is an alternative, which I can give you in that event, but is a bit more complicated to describe.

Comment: I made the changes that you recommended, it still did not help. Here it is, http://pastebin.com/XzTUHetN.

Comment: It looks like orgmode.org has an **ancient** version of MathJax installed (v1.0.1) that is several *years* out of date.  The configuration process that I gave you was added in v2.0, so that is why that isn't being loaded.  It may also be that `\DeclareMathOperator` was not in v1.0.1 (I kind of recall that it wasn't).  You should switch to `http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js` to get a current version.

Comment: This solved my problem! If you make this an answer I will accept it.
Many thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer above.  Both parts are needed to get your example to work properly in all browsers.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your answer for future readers).