# Org html export does not recognize mathjax's DeclareMathOperator?

Tags: html, org-mode, mathjax

When I export to html the following block in org-mode,

```
#+BEGIN_HTML
\(
\renewcommand{\Pr}{\mathbb{P}}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\mathbf{arg\,min}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\mathbf{arg\,max}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sup}{sup}
\)
#+END_HTML
```

The generated html complains that `DeclareMathOperator` is a undefined control sequence (it recognizes the `newcommand`). On examining the html, the mathjax config contains the following extensions.

```
extensions: ["tex2jax.js","TeX/AMSmath.js","TeX/AMSsymbols.js",
                     "TeX/noUndefined.js"],
```

So why is mathjax not recognizing the `DeclareMathOperator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537757/equivalent-of-declaremathoperator-in-mathjax/25538644?noredirect=1#comment39911448_25538644), the version of MathJax hosted at orgmode.org is ancient, and predates the inclusion of the `\DeclareMathOperator` macro.  You should change your source for MathJax to the MathJax CDN at http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/Mathjax.js in order to get the most up-to-date version.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your answer for future readers).